# cakephp 3.x default authentication don´t work

Tags: php, authentication, cakephp

at first, I´m very thankful for this great community, where I´ve learned a lot. You´re the very best. :)

Now I´m in trouble with the authentication. I have a simple user-login an I always get an error with the info the username or the password is false.
And I don´t know why. :(

I´m working nearby the official tutorial for cakephp 3.x. 
So here is my code for the AppController:

```
public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();

        $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
        $this->loadComponent('Flash');
        $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
            'authenticate' => [
                'Form' => [
                    'fields' => [
                        'username' => 'mail',
                        'password' => 'password'
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            'loginAction' => [
                'controller' => 'Users',
                'action' => 'login'
            ]
        ]);

        $this->Auth->allow(['display']);
    }
```

This is the code for the UsersController:

```
public function login(){

        if($this->request->is('post')){

            $user = $this->Auth->identify();
            if($user){
                $this->Auth->setUser($user);
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
            }
            $this->Flash->error('Name or Password is wrong');               
        }               
    }
```

Here is the code within my User.php (Entity):

```
protected function _setPassword($value){

        $hasher = new DefaultPasswordHasher();
        return $hasher->hash($value);
}
```

And that´s my view for this:

```
<h1>Login</h1>
<?= $this->Form->create() ?>
<?= $this->Form->input('email') ?>
<?= $this->Form->input('password') ?>
<?= $this->Form->button('Login') ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

It´s my first time I´m posting here and my very first time with CakePHP 3.0, so please help me. :)

Please forgive my worse english. ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your AppController you setted the username as "mail" and in your view you are calling the input name as "email".

Set the same username field in both AppController and in your view for login.

For example if your column name in your database is "email", your Auth component should look like this:

```
$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
    'authenticate' => [
        'Form' => [
            'fields' => [
                'username' => 'email',
                'password' => 'password'
            ]
        ]
    ],
    'loginAction' => [
        'controller' => 'Users',
        'action' => 'login'
    ]
]);
```

And your login view should be exactly like the one you have.

Comment: I was so blind. /doh Thank you soooo much!